# Why Nuxt3 SSG projects have an entry.js file?

Tags: performance, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, static-site-generation

I created a very simple Nuxt3 project with only two pages and a layout. Pages only have an h1.

I generate my project with `npm run generate` command and this is my output folder:

[image: Nuxt3 output folder]

Why I have `.js` files like `entry.9f5afebe.js` with a size of 137KB if i have only an h1?